# How to add hexadecimal numbers?

Tags: c, hex

I have homework where I need to calculate the checksum of INTEL HEX.
But I don't know how to add hex numbers.

```
char string[100] = ":10010000214601360121470136007EFE09D2190\n";
char hLength[5] = "0x", hHexSum[5] = "0x";
long length;
int i, hexSum = 0x0,x;

// We create hex format from first two numbers
hLength[2] = string[1];
hLength[3] = string[2];
hLength[4] = 0;

// Convert hex to dec number
length = (strtol(hLength, 0, 0))*2;
x = strlen(string);

// Add all hex numbers
for (i = 1; i <= (x-1); i++)
{
    hHexSum[2] = string[i];
    hHexSum[3] = string[i+1];
    hHexSum[4] = 0;
    printf("%d + %s ", hexSum, hHexSum);
    hexSum = hexSum + hHexSum;
    i = i + 1;
    printf("DEC = %d; HEX = %x\n", hexSum, hexSum);
}

printf("%#08x\n", hexSum);

system("pause");
return 0;
```

Output is now:

```
0 + 0x10 DEC = 7338140; HEX = 6ff89c
7338140 + 0x01 DEC = 14676280; HEX = dff138
14676280 + 0x00 DEC = 22014420; HEX = 14fe9d4 
... and more
```

But if I am right, correct output should be:

```
0 + 0x10 DEC = 16; HEX = 10
... and more
```

And I don't know how I can fix it.

// UPDATE it's weird but I get different dec and hex values every time I compile it.

Comment: The line `hexSum = hexSum + hHexSum;` adds and `int` (`hexSum`)  and the address  of an array (`hHexsum`). Not sure it is what you mean. But can you precise how the checksum must be calculated. From your code, it seems that you read pairs of hex digits convert them to a byte and add them altogether. Right?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and mind them.

Comment: @AlainMerigot Yes i need to add all pairs from string. So 0x10 + 0x01 + 0x00 ...
Maybe i can try to remove 0x from hHexSum and convert it to INT.

Comment: @pmg enabled still no warnings or errors.

Comment: I suspect you do not have **all warnings** enabled: [`int = int + char[]` should emit a warning or, even better, an error](https://ideone.com/npxogH)

Comment: @pmg Ou thank. And what can i do to add it correct? I cant add hexes together? Should i first convert it to dec and then add it probably.

Comment: Addind an integer and a string (like `"0xAB"`, or `"42"`, or `"pmg"`) does not do what you want. You need to convert the string to an integer (note that DEC and HEX are all the same internally: `"42"` and `"0x2A"` both convert to `42` or `0x2A`)

Comment: Your input string is missing 3 hex digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the culprit:

```
hexSum = hexSum + hHexSum;
```

`hexSum` is an integer, correctly initialized with 0, fine until there...

but `hHexSum` is a `char[5]`. In the above expression it decays to a pointer to its first element, so the result of the sum is a pointer to the character of index `hexSum` in the array, which is not what you want.

You convert that pointer to an integer and use it as if it were the expected sum, what it is not. BTW a decent compiler should raise a warning here for *convertion of a .pointer to integer without a cast*.

You should use `strtol` to correctly convert the string `hHexSum` to its integer **value** before adding it to `hexSum`.